# gluBuild2DMipmaps sometimes crashes

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glu

I'm loading a texture image:

```
//glGenTextures... glBindTexture...
BYTE* image = (BYTE*) malloc(256 * 256 * 3);
FILE* imageFile;
errno_t err = fopen_s(&imageFile, fileName, "rb");
if (err != 0){
    perror("Error loading file");
    return false;
}
fread(image, 256 * 256 * 3, 1, imageFile);
fclose(imageFile);
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 3, 256, 256, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

I am building it in VS2013, and it always works when I execute it in VS. However when I copy out the executable and run it there, it *sometimes* works which is strange. I have completely no idea why it is happening.

The texture is 256x256 in .data format (raw data).

Comment: Your enums should start with GLU instead of GL to begin with. Not sure if that changes anything.

Comment: @Andreas If I change them to `GLU_`, none of them are declared.

Comment: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluBuild2DMipmaps.xml

Comment: @Andreas I believe it is different on Windows actually: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368652(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Ok. At least I learned something today :-) Could you give more details in your post regarding system (windows) and what you mean by "sometimes" and "works".

Comment: @Andreas When the program crashes at `gluBuild2DMipmaps` I simply kill it and execute it again. Repeat this process and the program will eventually run with expected behaviors (no crash, texture are loaded correctly). When the program is run in VS, it never crashes. This is on Windows 8.1.

Comment: You should also check for opengl errors before and after the call you find suspicious when debugging. Maybe you get an OUT_OF_MEMORY error in which case your context is in an undeterminate state.

Comment: @Andreas Apparently the heap is corrupted (checked with `_heapchk() != _HEAPOK`) and most probably the problem lies before `gluBuild2DMipmaps` is executed...

Comment: @Andreas Got it figured out... The reason the memory is corrupted is because of my call to `glLightfv`.

Comment: First of all, check value returned by `fread()`, it can be something wrong with file

Comment: While we're on the topic of heap corruption... you realize the failure case here leaks 192 KiB of memory? You should probably check to see if the file is readable and 192 KiB or larger before you allocate that buffer ;)

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman Ah, thanks for catching that.